# Prove that there is $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=cx$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable such that $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all $x,t\in \mathbb{R}$. Then there is $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that  $f(x)=cx$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Any suggestions how to deal with this problem. Thanks

Comment: Its differentiable, not derivable. You want to show the derivative is constant, use the definition.

Answer (score 2):

We know that any $x\in \mathbb R$ can be written as $x\cdot 1$. Now let $c=f(1)$. Then $f(x) =f(x\cdot 1)=x\cdot f(1)=cx$.

Comment: It needs not be differentiable $f$

Comment: You don't need in the hypothesis that the function should be differentiable but it turns out to be differentiable in the end.

Comment: The absolute value is a counterexample to what you proved.

Comment: @kduna The absolute value doesn't satisfy $f(tx) =tf(x)$

Comment: I just realized how dumb that was as your comment came up.